# $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ is it possible to find an angle $\theta $ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r\cos\theta = a$ and $r\sin\theta = b$

Tags: calculus

I'm studying calculus and this question came to me:

$\forall  a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ is it possible to find an angle $\theta $ and a number $r\in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\left\{\begin{matrix}
r\cos\theta=a  & \\ r\sin\theta =b
 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$

?

Comment: Yes, $r$ and $\theta$ are so-called polar-coordinates.

Comment: See this article on the [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $a$ and $b$ represent rectangular coordinates, and they are more commonly represented as $x$ and $y$ respectively. This is basically transforming the rectangular coordinates $(x,y)$ into polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.

You have $r\cos\theta = x$ and $r\sin\theta = y$.

Squaring both equations and adding you get: $r^2\cos^2 \theta + r^2\sin^2\theta = x^2 + y^2$, which can be rewritten $r^2(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) = x^2 + y^2$, and employing a well known trigonometric identity gives $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$. So $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Now dividing one equation by the other, we get $\frac{r\sin\theta}{r\cos\theta} = \frac yx$, which gives $\tan \theta = \frac yx$. The value of $\theta$ you take depends on the signs of $x$ and $y$ and hence the quadrant you're working in.

In this fashion, you can easily work out both $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: In a programming or calculator scenario, "working out the quadrant" can be more work than just using $\operatorname{atan2}$.

Comment: What i dont understand is something more particular. Suppose we have the point [3,1]. 

I can use an **INFINITE** number of combinations of $r$ and $\theta$ in order to satisfy $rcos\theta=3$. But incredibly,among these infinite combinations, only **ONE** combination of $r$ and $\theta$ is able to satisfy $rcos\theta=3$ **AND** $rsin\theta=1$. Why? ( it's a more subtle math question)